# SSD's "Used" space growing after each Erase / Format & ejecting!

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, partition, ssd, apfs

I bought a brand new Samsung T7 SSD, and I used macOS's Disk Utility to format (erase) it in APFS(Encrypted), scheme: GUID Partition Map.
Before erasing (brand new), "Used" space was 108,5 MB.
After first erasing, "Used" space was 20 kb.
Then I erased it again (same way as before - APFS(Encrypted, scheme: GUID Partition Map).
After second erase "Used" space was 766 kb!
Then I erased it as MacOS Extended(Journaled).
After this 3rd erase "Used" space was 852 MB!
Then I erased it back the same way as in 1st and 2nd erase -APFS(Encrypted, scheme: GUID Partition Map).
After this 4th erase "Used" space went back to 766 kb.
Then I erased it to exFat.
And then back to APFS(Encrypted, scheme: GUID Partition Map).
After this 5th and 6th erase "Used" space was to 725 kb.
Then I ejected it and plugged in back to my MacBook and "Used" space was 750 kb.
Then I ejected it and plugged in back to my MacBook one more time and "Used" space is now 762 kb.

What's going on???
After first such erase - APFS(Encrypted, scheme: GUID Partition Map) - it was just 20 kb.

And I can't go back to 20 kb again!
What's going on? How can I go back to 20 kb of "Used" space?
Please help!

P.S.
After erasing it's showing in Disk Utility like this:
[image]

But after I reopen Disk Utility, it shows like this again:
[image]

Hidden files:
[image]

Comment: Is there a reason that you really need that ~680 kB back, or are you just curious about what stuff is on your formatted drive?

Comment: I just wanted to make sure I've formatted it properly.
And also want to know why this space is growing and how much more can it grow :D
Basically, understand what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

750 kB is so small, that this could easily be Spotlight indexing and other invisible files. Can you do <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> in a Finder window of the empty disk to see hidden files? The original 20kB may have been a fluke before any of the files were added.

About the pictures, Disk Utility often doesn’t realize that the old partition has been deleted and shows 2 partitions that are each 2 TB (impossible). Restarting Disk Utility returns it to a normal state.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue!
I solved it by connecting the SSD to my Android phone.

All the files that I deleted went to `.Trashes` folder apparently, which is not shown on Mac even after pressing <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> for some reason.

I connected the SSD to my Android phone, and I found the deleted files in the `.Trashes` folder, I deleted it, and now it works perfectly.

Just make sure to choose the right folder before beginning the deletion process.

[image: Photo of a Samsung SSD connected to an Android phone showing the files with the .Trashes folder highlighted]

[image: Photo of Android phone showing the 'Details' of the .Trashes folder being 166 GB, Last modified on June 6, 2022 12:05 AM containing 11304 files, 2805 folders]

Comment: MacOS will expect (and indeed require) a .Trashes folder. I would not recommend deleting it.

Answer (score 0):

`.Trashes`, `.Spotlight-V100`, and `.fseventsd` folders are essential parts of the Mac filing system.

`.Trashes` is where files go when you send them to the Trash, unsurprisingly.

`.Spotlight-V100` is the index for Spotlight. This will grow in size, as the files get more numerous.

`.fseventd` contains log files of system events on the disk.

I would not recommend deleting them -- and certainly not just to save KILObytes.

Answer (score 0):

There are  hidden folders and files which can only be  seen on PC .... - .DS, trashes, spotlight...

Format USB stick as exFat find PC and have look what 'empty' device looks like in MacOs

Comment: Can you please add some details about how this answers the question the OP asked?